# How to save real PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox

I need to save picturebox with real image as displayed.
Help me?

Ex:

[image]

```
Dim myEncoder As Encoder
    Dim myImageCodecInfo As ImageCodecInfo
    Dim myEncoderParameter As EncoderParameter
    Dim myEncoderParameters As EncoderParameters
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(imgJpgPng.Image, Bitmap)
    Dim bmpt As New Bitmap(640, 640)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpt)
        g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmpt.Width, bmpt.Height)
    End Using
    myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    myEncoder = Encoder.Quality
    myEncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1)
    myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, CType(75L, Int32))
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
    bmpt.Save("d:\ImgTemp\0000.JPG", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to crop the image.  Doesnt have much to do with a picturebox, real or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm getting is that you want to save the picture box image, maybe to a directory or something. So, lets get right into this(It's very simple. By the way, I noticed you have Dim'd the bmpt at 640, 640, maybe that's a problem.

This is how I would save a picture box image

PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Webcam Application poctures\Picture.jpg")

Its very self explanatory, Picturebox1.Image.Save(saving the image) and in the quotations, there's the directory, and at the end there' a jpg, you can make it a .png, or any other file format.
If you want to have it being displayed as the original picture in the picture box, you will need to goto the properties of the picture box and make it bigger(size) or use the stretch feature.

Edit: I'm sorry I didn't read your question right, here's an update!

Read this website's information and look into it, this will help you greatly!
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_resize_picture_save.html